# kerberos apache php partialy working

Tags: php, apache, kerberos

have a problem with kerberos authentication on apache php
Setup = RHEL 7
apache 2.4 from rhscl
php7 from rhscl configured with php-fpm

Kerberos is working perfectly on http://site.domain/
but not on http://site.domain/index.php

The same problem occurs for all sub directories when accessing a .php file.

There is a rewrite for php to fcgi in the vhost setup.

index.php => $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']

vhost setup

```
<VirtualHost *:443 > 
  ## Vhost docroot
 DocumentRoot /opt/code70

 <Directory /opt/code70>
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    Options FollowSymLinks
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing HTMLTable VersionSort IgnoreCase
    IndexOrderDefault Descending Date
    IndexIgnore *.php

    AuthType Kerberos
AuthName "Kerberos"
KrbMethodNegotiate On
KrbMethodK5Passwd On
KrbAuthRealms ....
....    
KrbVerifyKDC Off
KrbSaveCredentials Off
KrbLocalUserMapping On
KrbAuthoritative On
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require valid-user
</Directory>

## SSL directives
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile      ......
SSLProtocol             -ALL +TLSv1
SSLCipherSuite           ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
SSLHonorCipherOrder     On
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://localhost:9000/opt/code70/$1   
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: share your `code`, `server` configs, `.htaccess` etc...

Comment: Can you clarify what error message are you seeing?  I see a problem in the httpd configuration file you posted, but we need to know more.